# How to call Objective-C "self" from C method

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have `Objective-C` class in my `iOS` project that implements `Objective-C` and `C` code in the same class. I changed the extension to `.mm` and this part goes well. Now I want to set a `C` method that will call the `Objective-C` method in the same class. The problem I get is when I am trying to call `self` from the `C` method.
Here is the code :

```
void SetNotificationListeners(){
    [self fireSpeechRecognition];
}
```

the error is  :

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'self'
```

how can I manage this?

Comment: That's iOS, not IOS. Anyway, why do you expect `self` to be accessible from within a function that does **not** belong to the class? That just doesn't make sense. You'll need to pass in the instance (object) itself as an argument.

Comment: Why have you changed the extension to `.mm` when you are using Objective-C and C (you don't mention C++)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to pass the instance pointer to the C function:

```
void SetNotificationListeners(void *uData)
{
    MyClass *obj = (__bridge MyClass *)(uData);
    [obj fireSpeechRecognition];
}

- (void)myMethod
{
    // Call C function from Objective-C method:
    myFunction((__bridge void *)(self));
}
```

(The "brigde" stuff is needed only if you compile with ARC.)

Comment: Reading this post i ask, where in C you call Objective C ? Here you said "Call C function FROM Objective-C"... doesnt understand ...this make me confusion! rs

Answer (score 3):

Either give self as an argument to the function call:

```
void SetNotificationListeners(void *myObj){
[(MyClass*)myObj fireSpeechRecognition];
}

//in objC
SetNotificationListeners(self);
```

or have a global variable that holds reference

```
//global variable
static MyClass *myObj;

//in obj c
myObj = self;
SetNotificationListeners(); //use myObj instead of self in function
```

The first is better in my opinion.

Comment: The second is madness :)

Comment: As I said Id prefer the first option. Funny how I get down voted when the marked answer with 10 up votes in the now found duplicate of this question just mentions the same "madness"....

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to change the file extension. Objective-C is a superset of C, which means you can use plain C in your Objective-C files as you please.

When you write an implementation of an Objective-C method, that method always executes in context of some particular *instance*, that’s the `self` part. You get the `self` in an Objective-C method automagically, but behind the scenes it’s just passed as an argument to the method, see [`obc_msgsend`](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-16-lets-build-objc_msgsend.html).

Your plain C function is not a part of the class (plain C functions never are), therefore there’s no instance associated with it when you call it, there’s no implicit `self`. If you want the function to call some instance, you have to pass the pointer to that instance explicitly. For example some of the plain C APIs have a “context” pointer you can pass when registering for a callback. See the neighboring answers for examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C methods there are two parameters that are implicitly passed into each method, which are `self` and `_cmd`. This is why you can access `self` from within a method.

You could just pass `self` as an argument to your c function when calling from an Objective-C method, but with that trivial example I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use a method.

You do not need to change the file extension to `.mm` unless you are using Objective-C++